# Program dynamically added buttons in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im trying to add code to dynamically added buttons in Xamarin forms. How do i add funtionality to the buttons created by the following code

```
   private async void Buttons(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ContentPage {
            Content = new StackLayout {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Button { Text = "Button1" },
                    new Button { Text = "Button2" },
                    new Button { Text = "Button3" }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code, hope it will helpful for you.

```
var MainLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Red
        };

        var button1 = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Button 1"                
        };

        var button2 = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Button 2"
        };

        var button3 = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Button 3"
        };

        button1.Clicked += Button1_Clicked;
        button2.Clicked += Button2_Clicked;
        button3.Clicked += Button3_Clicked;

        MainLayout.Children.Add(button1);
        MainLayout.Children.Add(button2);
        MainLayout.Children.Add(button3);

        Content = MainLayout;
```

Button Click Methods

```
private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert","Button 1 Clicked", "Ok");
    }

    private void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert", "Button 2 Clicked", "Ok");
    }

    private void Button3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Alert", "Button 3 Clicked", "Ok");
    }
```

Output :

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use the `Button`s with events (which would usually be the way to go without a viewmodel), there is simply no way to use the initiallizers the way you did. You can't subscribe to an event via the object initializer

You'd have to create the buttons from outside the array initializer

```cs
private void CreateContent()
{
    var button1 = new Button()
                      { 
                          Text = "Button 1"
                      };
    button1.Click += Button1_OnClick;

    var button2 = new Button()
                      { 
                          Text = "Button 2"
                      };
    // and so on
    return new ContentPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = { button1, button2, button3 }
                }
    }
}

private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // handle button 1 bein clicked
}
```

Anyway, this way, you'd have the event handlers in the page that navigates to the next page, which would be worse than having the event handlers in the page that displays the controls. I'd rather subclass `ContentPage` and create the content from the constructor. Then you can have the event handlers in that class. The calling page does not have to have any knowledge about the internals (neither the contents, nor the behavior) of the page it navigates to. Even if you do not want to use MVVM (which I'd recommend), you could think about using XAML to create the new page. From that you could subscribe to the event with a simple attribute in your *MyPage.xaml*

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Button 1" Click="Button1_OnClick" />
    <Button Text="Button 2" Click="Button2_OnClick" />
    <Button Text="Button 3" Click="Button3_OnClick" />
</StackLayout>
```

and in your *MyPage.xaml.cs*

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    // ...

    public void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // whatever
    }

    public void Button2_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // whatever
    }

    public void Button3_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```